# How to get CSV data to work with basemap, CRS issues

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, openstreetmap

I am having problems aligning my own data in CSV format into a base-map from quickmapservices. Only one or the other will show depending on which I add first. Not sure where the problem lies.[image: CSV import with sample data]

[image: csv. data once imported showing on project]

[image: same project with attempt to add base-map, nothing occurs though]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. The good news is that you've come across the single most common issue here. The bad news is that your Question doesn't give enough detail of what you have tried to tell you where you went wrong. The root problem is like failure to understand the difference between spatial reference assignment and reprojection. If you assigned the CRS correctly, your features would draw together. Please [Edit] the Question to detail your exact procedure.

Comment: Can you add some sample data from your csv file to your question? What coordinate system are they in?

Comment: Looks like your lat/lon values are switched. Latitude of -122 does not exist. Try setting your x field to latitude and y field to longitude.

Comment: @MrXsquared, that did the trick! thank you.

Comment: @MrXsquared please convert your comment to an answer